# Android: How to make Circle through xml which looks like a halo

Tags: android, xml, geometry

I am trying to make a circle using xml with a halo. The halo would be like it starts with say green color in the center, the greenish color keeps fading and finally at the edges it becomes transparent.

How to go about it?

I am trying to use following:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <gradient   android:centerColor="@drawable/light_green" android:gradientRadius="250" android:type="radial"
         android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

Still not able to get the desired effect. Any lead would be helpful.

Comment: Why not use a Custom View?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:centerColor="#88FF0000"
        android:centerX="50%p"
        android:centerY="50%p"
        android:endColor="#00FF0000"
        android:gradientRadius="50%p"
        android:startColor="#FFFF0000"
        android:type="radial" />
       <size
           android:height="80dp"
           android:width="80dp" />

</shape>
```

Change color code and change centerColor's alpha code as per your requirement

Comment: after applying this to the background of my view, there is a very very tiny dot that is visible, nothing else.

Comment: it still didn't work for me, however when I changed the gradientRaidus to 70, it works :). thanks.

Comment: beautiful glow <3