# How to implement circle shape for textview in android?

Tags: android

how to show to circle shape in textview

i done the xml like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <corners android:radius="2dip" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dip"
        android:color="#FF0000" />

    <solid android:color="#FF0000" />

    <size
        android:height="25dp"
        android:width="15dp" />

</shape>
```

but it is showing in oval shape but i need a circle shape

Any one Help me....

Comment: check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31422843/android-how-to-make-circle-through-xml-which-looks-like-a-halo/31428287#31428287

Comment: Because your height is different from your width (`25dp != 15dp`). To get a **circle**, they must be **equal**.

Answer (score 1):

try this :
 cirlce.xml in your drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:shape="oval" >
    <gradient android:startColor="@color/red_color"
              android:endColor="@color/red_color"
              android:angle="360"/>
</shape>
```

now set drawable background to your `TextView`.

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtView"
    android:layout_width="20dip"
    android:layout_height="20dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"  <!-- circle drawable background.-->
    android:text="5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white_color"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a circle shape, both width and height need to be the same. In your xml the `<size>` tag specifies height bigger than width, hence the oval. The following code will make it show up as a circle:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <corners android:radius="2dip" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dip"
        android:color="#FF0000" />

    <solid android:color="#FF0000" />

    <size
        android:height="25dp"
        android:width="25dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: same i am getting ovel shape

Comment: @ManikantaReddy Did you fix the issue?